# How to find Steinmetz parameters from datasheet?

Tags: datasheet, ferrite, core

Given a certain core material I would like to know where and how I can extract the Steinmetz parameter from its datasheet. Hope someone can help me out. Thanks.

datasheet:

https://en.tdk.eu/inf/80/db/fer_13/R4180x2620x1250.pdf

https://en.tdk.eu/download/528882/6a0da25e2745be5c13b587b3d4a8de48/pdf-n87.pdf

Comment: post the datasheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core loss equation is in the form \$P_{loss}=a\times B_{pk}^b \times f^c\$.

Where \$P_{loss}\$ is the core loss density, \$B_{pk}\$ is half the AC flux swing, and \$f\$ is the frequency.  \$a\$, \$b\$, and \$c\$ are constants for the given material.

The data sheet for the material gives you curves for \$P_{loss}\$ vs. \$B_{pk}\$ and \$P_{loss}\$ vs. frequency at different values of \$B_{pk}\$.

From there you can use a curve fitting routine (Matlab, Mathcad, hand calculation, etc.) to get the constants.

It may be easier to call or email applications support for the product and see if they can help you.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your answer to convert the equations and make them easier to read.  You may want to check I haven't messed anything up, or accidentally changed the meaning.